# How to implement a reader class with the use of DataInputStream

Tags: java, datainputstream

I'm trying to learn how to implement a reader class to only implement needed methods to read certain data type inputs. I came across the following code on geeksforgeeks, but I don't really understand the use of buffersize or bytes or datainputstream etc. I was wondering if anybody could help break down the code, or point me in the right direction so some relevant resources?

```
// Working program using Reader Class
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {
    static class Reader {
        final private int BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 16;
        private DataInputStream din;
        private byte[] buffer;
        private int bufferPointer, bytesRead;
 
        public Reader()
        {
            din = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            bufferPointer = bytesRead = 0;
        }
 
        public Reader(String file_name) throws IOException
        {
            din = new DataInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(file_name));
            buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            bufferPointer = bytesRead = 0;
        }
 
        public String readLine() throws IOException
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[64]; // line length
            int cnt = 0, c;
            while ((c = read()) != -1) {
                if (c == '\n') {
                    if (cnt != 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                buf[cnt++] = (byte)c;
            }
            return new String(buf, 0, cnt);
        }
 
        public int nextInt() throws IOException
        {
            int ret = 0;
            byte c = read();
            while (c <= ' ') {
                c = read();
            }
            boolean neg = (c == '-');
            if (neg)
                c = read();
            do {
                ret = ret * 10 + c - '0';
            } while ((c = read()) >= '0' && c <= '9');
 
            if (neg)
                return -ret;
            return ret;
        }
 
        public long nextLong() throws IOException
        {
            long ret = 0;
            byte c = read();
            while (c <= ' ')
                c = read();
            boolean neg = (c == '-');
            if (neg)
                c = read();
            do {
                ret = ret * 10 + c - '0';
            } while ((c = read()) >= '0' && c <= '9');
            if (neg)
                return -ret;
            return ret;
        }
 
        public double nextDouble() throws IOException
        {
            double ret = 0, div = 1;
            byte c = read();
            while (c <= ' ')
                c = read();
            boolean neg = (c == '-');
            if (neg)
                c = read();
 
            do {
                ret = ret * 10 + c - '0';
            } while ((c = read()) >= '0' && c <= '9');
 
            if (c == '.') {
                while ((c = read()) >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                    ret += (c - '0') / (div *= 10);
                }
            }
 
            if (neg)
                return -ret;
            return ret;
        }
 
        private void fillBuffer() throws IOException
        {
            bytesRead = din.read(buffer, bufferPointer = 0,
                                 BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (bytesRead == -1)
                buffer[0] = -1;
        }
 
        private byte read() throws IOException
        {
            if (bufferPointer == bytesRead)
                fillBuffer();
            return buffer[bufferPointer++];
        }
 
        public void close() throws IOException
        {
            if (din == null)
                return;
            din.close();
        }
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
        Reader s = new Reader();
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int k = s.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        while (n-- > 0) {
            int x = s.nextInt();
            if (x % k == 0)
                count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need any of this. `DataInputStream` already has `readLine()`, `readInt()`, `readLong()`, etc. If you're trying to parse ASCII input you should be using `java.util.Scanner`. Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make much sense: a `DataInputStream` is used to read binary data. Here, only the `read` method that reads one byte is used, and a simple `InputStream` can do that.

Answer (score -1):

InputStream has a function read that take in bytes to a buffer then you need to cast to a primitive we use buffered read becasue direct file access is slow. Also its suggested you use java.nio.file with better like BufferedReader which perform alot of other handy tools with methods like readLine(). nio stands for new io.

Comment: hmmm but bufferedreader cant read in single integers right, would reading in a line of integers as string and then parsing them as integers be alot slower?

Comment: **I/O is slow**.  Anything you can do to increase the amount of data you read in one I/O call speeds things up immensely.  The cost of parsing out the integers from a string you've already read into memory is **virtually nothing**, compared to what it would have cost to input the characters of that string one-by-one.